# jQuery is not defined print partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to prepare content and print it when button is clicked. But I have got error.

index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<button>Get External Content</button>

<br />
<div id="printForm">

</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('button').click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("MyPartialView")',
                data: {
                    'p': "xxx"
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#printForm').empty();
                    $('#printForm').html(result);
                    $('#printForm').print();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    // bu kısımda eğer ajax işlemi başarısız ise
                    // hata mesajı verebiliriz.
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jQuery.print.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyPartialView(string p=null)
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

MyPartialView.cshtml:

```
<span id="manchego"></span>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { //here is error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
        $("#manchego").kendoBarcode({
            value: "2346722",
            type: "ean8",
            width: 280,
            height: 100
        });
    });
</script>
```

if I comment print method  it works fine. But `$('#printForm').print();` is not working. 
error : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I don't have to use jquery.print.js. How should I  printing partial view?

Comment: I suspect that , jquery is defined more than once . Are you sure they are consistent ?

Comment: if I do print method  in jquery.ready in partila view it works. @sepehr                                                                     div id="ppp">
    <span id="manchego"></span>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#manchego").kendoBarcode({
            value: "2346722",
            type: "ean8",
            width: 280,
            height: 100
        });
        $("#ppp").print();
    });
</script>

Comment: once I had problem with kendo grid excel export when grid was added with ajax, and solution was removing redundant jquery ,anyway I`m waiting for a solution to your problem too